# Why the method uses Activator.CreateInstance instead of directly "new Class()"?

Tags: c#

In the method `GetNotificationCorrespondingToDomainEvent` in
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Infrastructure/Services/DomainEventService.cs, it has the following method,

```
private INotification GetNotificationCorrespondingToDomainEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent)
{
    return (INotification)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(DomainEventNotification<>).MakeGenericType(domainEvent.GetType()), domainEvent)!;
}
```

How it compares with `new DomainEventNotification(....)`? BTW, is the `!` at the end necessary?

```
private INotification GetNotificationCorrespondingToDomainEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent)
{
    return new DomainEventNotification<DomainEvent>(domainEvent)!;
}
```

Comment: `DomainEvent` most likely has multiple derived types, and you cannot tell rightaway what exact type `domainEvent` is. `MakeGenericType` allows you to switch an expression of `Type` type to `...<Type>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that

```
return (INotification)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(DomainEventNotification<>).MakeGenericType(domainEvent.GetType()), domainEvent)!;
```

creates an instance with the *dynamic type* of `domainEvent`. So if the actual argument is `MyDerivedDomainEvent`, it creates an instance of `DomainEventNotification<MyDerivedDomainEvent>`. There's not enough context to tell whether that makes sense, but that's what happens.

`Activator.CreateInstance()` has the return type `object?`, so the `!` is necessary to prevent the nullability warning. One could question why they selected the return type to be nullable, because I don't think it will ever return null.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-object())), "The method returns null for the Nullable<T> instances with no value." -- so `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(int?))` returns null.

Comment: @KirkWoll Oh, thanks. Learned a thing again.

Comment: @KirkWoll Kinda weird edge-case, because any `null` is castable to a nullable anyway https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIQTsc